# What's the fastest way to calculate a bit mask from the sign of an Int?

Tags: haskell, integer-arithmetic

Yes, I know this is a somewhat insane question. Please don't bother asking if I really need to know the answer or if this is really where "my" problem is. Thanks.

There are times when the following function is very nice to have:

```
isNeg# :: Int# -> Int#
isNeg# x
   | x <# 0#   = -1#
   | otherwise = 0#
```

For example, it could be used like this:

```
cc# f x y = word2Int# (f (int2Word# x) (int2Word# y))

andi# x y = cc# and# x y
xori# x y = cc# xor# x y
ori# x y = cc# or# x y

ifNegFstElseSnd# :: Int# -> Int# -> Int#
ifNegFstElseSnd# x y = case isNeg# x of
                         n -> ori# (andi# n y) (xori# n y)
```

When the above definition of `isNeg` is compiled using GHC 7.6.3 with -fllvm and -O2, it produces

```
# BB#0:                                 # %ci4
    movq    (%rbp), %rax
    testq   %r14, %r14
    js      .LBB0_2
# BB#1:                                 # %nid
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    jmpq    *%rax  # TAILCALL
.LBB0_2:                                # %cic
    movq    $-1, %rbx
    jmpq    *%rax  # TAILCALL
```

The problem is that `js` is a conditional jump, and these seem to be considered efficiency problems for very tight loops (where everything is already unboxed, etc). An alternative is to write

```
isNeg# :: Int# -> Int#
isNeg# x = uncheckedIShiftRA# x (intSize# -# 1#)
  where
    intSize# = case bitSize (undefined::Int) of
                 I# size -> size
```

This produces

```
# BB#0:                                 # %cny
    sarq    $63, %r14
    movq    (%rbp), %rax
    movq    %r14, %rbx
    jmpq    *%rax  # TAILCALL
```

This is very straightforward, but I'm given to understand that shifts (`sarq`) are relatively slow operations.

Another option that seems very reasonable is

```
isNeg2# :: Int# -> Int#
isNeg2# x = negateInt# ( dataToTag# (x <# 0#) )
```

This, sadly, produces utterly horrible code that's not even worth pasting here.

#### The question

1. Is there a better way?
2. Would upgrading to GHC 7.8.2 and rewriting the last definition as

   isNeg2# x = negateInt# (x <# 0#)
   -- (Note: edited to correct an earlier error)

to match the new types give something really wonderful? I can't test it because I don't have GHC 7.8.2.

Comment: On GHC 7.8.2 -fllvm `negateInt# (x <# 0#)` compiles to the exact same code as your `isNeg#`.

Comment: By the way, it's always good to consult the [bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CopyIntegerSign) in cases like this. It has a section on sign bits.

Comment: I don't believe shifting is slow anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the info, AndrásKovács! @augustss, I hope you're right, but do you have anything to back that up?

Comment: @AndrásKovács, regarding your first comment, it compiles to the exact same code as *which* `isNeg#`?

Comment: @dfeuer, sorry, I meant the `isNeg` with the `uncheckedISHiftRA`.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, even on processors a couple of years old the shift latency was 1 cycle, and throughput was 2 shifts per cycle.   https://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the prims have changed since GHC 7.6.3.  For example, comparison no longer results in a boolean.  This means your `isNeg#` function should instead read:

```
isNeg# :: Int# -> Int#
isNeg# x
   = negateInt# (x <# 0#)
```

This produces (7.8.2, -O2):

```
_cMj:
        testq %r14,%r14
        setl %al
        movzbl %al,%ebx
        negq %rbx
        jmp *(%rbp)
```

Edit: And the  LLVM code includes an `sar` instruction (not `sarq` oddly) so if that bothers you for some reason then perhaps you should avoid LLVM.

Comment: My last line of code (which I was trying to write 7.8.2-style) was originally wrong--my brain malfunctioned when I was editing the GHC 7.6.3 code to 7.8.2 code, and I had no way to test it. I'm only concerned about shifts if they're slow. augustss thinks they no longer are.